# How to implement PayPal IPN listener (controller) in Play Framework Scala

Tags: scala, paypal, playframework, paypal-ipn

I am currently using PayPal buttons in my application written in Scala (Play Framework).

Now I am trying to implement PayPal IPN instead of redirect. 
According to PayPal document

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

After the user finished the payment, the flow of events is:

1. PayPal posts a message to my application's listener with all sorts of variables.
2. My listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response.
3. My listener performs an HTTP POST to send the complete, unaltered notification back to PayPal.
4. PayPal sends a single word back - either VERIFIED or INVALID.

So, my controller's method should look like:

```
  def payPalIpn() = Action { implicit request =>
    .... Get all PayPal Variables .......

    /* Send empty response with empty HTTP 200 response */
    Ok("")

    .... Make a POST request to PayPal site with all original PayPal's variables

  }
```

Here is what I stumbled upon - How can I make a POST request after I return OK("")?
Is that even possible in Play?

Appreciate if someone can give me any idea.

Andrei.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an excellent use case for an Akka Actor:

```
def payPalIpn() = Action { implicit request =>
    .... Get all PayPal Variables .......

   actorSystem.actorSelection("paypal-ipn-actor") ! ValidateIPN(request.body)

    /* Send empty response with empty HTTP 200 response */
    Ok("")

  }
```

Comment: this is very intersting for me. Can you elaborate more on this? What is paypal-ipn-actor and ValidateIPN ? Where and how do I define them? (sorry I never used Akka... )

Comment: "paypal-ipn-actor" would be the string by which you find the Actor (you) created to handle the event in the background. ValidateIPN would be a case object that gets sent to the Actor so it knows what it is doing. All Actors have a receive method with a case statement that checks what is incoming and acts accordingly based upon the data stream received. The web site is free to hand off the request and the Actor does it's work in the background (asynchronously). All well documented: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html

Comment: PS: Here is a gist https://gist.github.com/mslinn/4382183 on how the actual guts of such an Actor might be implemented. It is NOT an Actor but I used this as somewhat of a reference model to build one...

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems there is no way around learning and doing the basics of akka + play. I got quite used to the "copy-paste-adapt" pattern. Thanks for the links!

Comment: :) Kinda the design pattern of the framework of life -- always lots of easy and tempting paths until you eventually hit their respective dead ends...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correct, you want to make a POST request to PayPal in your action. For that you can use WS Client library from Play. Detailed tutorial is given at 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaWS

Comment: The problem is - How to make Post AFTER sending Http 200 response.

Comment: Did you tried creating Future of POST Request before sending response. Schedule it little later so that it executes after sending the response, I know it is hack but near to good solution,

Comment: Thank you. It sounds doable. I'll try it out.